# how to convert Async.js parallel to Bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, async.js

With async.js i can be able to define promises(i know its only functions) with handlers and its give me polymorphism with different handlers also results are **seperated**.
Can i do this in bluebird ?

```
async.parallel({
              cityPromises:  (cb)=>{
                  City.find({
                      areaId: {$in:locations.city}
                  }).then(result=> cb(null,result))
              },
              townPromises:  (cb)=>{
                  Town.find({
                      areaId: {$in:locations.town}
                  }).then(result=>cb(null,result))
              },
              quarterPromises:  (cb)=>{
                  Quarter.find({
                      areaId: {$in:locations.quarter}
                  }).then(result=>cb(null,result))
              }
          },(err,promises)=>{
              let {cityPromises, townPromises, quarterPromises} = promises
          })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching i made this.
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html

```
let promisesObject ={
              cities: City
                .find({
                    areaId: {$in:locations.city}
                })
                .select({ name: 1, areaId: 1})
                .exec(),

              towns:   Town
                .find({
                    areaId: {$in:locations.town}
                })
                .select({ name: 1, areaId: 1})
                .exec(),
              quarters: Quarter
                .find({
                    areaId: {$in:locations.quarter}
                })
                .select({ name: 1, areaId: 1})
                .exec()
          }

promise.props(promisesObject)
       .then((result) =>{
           let {cities, towns, quarters} = result
       });
```

Comment: also https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/bluebird/Bluebird/props